# Explain MySQL explain execution plan maths, difference between two plans

Tags: mysql, performance, explain, sql-execution-plan

I've got a basic MySQL performance question related to explain. I have two queries that return the same result and I am trying to understand how to make sense of the `EXPLAIN` of the execution plans.

The table has 50000 records in it and I am performing a record comparison. My first query takes 18.625 secs to run. The explain plan is as follows.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                   key         key_len ref                                 rows    filtered    Extra
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   SIMPLE      a       ALL     NULL                            NULL        NULL    NULL                                49520   100.00  
1   SIMPLE      b       ref     scoreEvent,eventScore           eventScore  4       olympics.a.eventId                  413     100.00      Using where; Using index; Not exists
1   SIMPLE      c       ref     PRIMARY,scoreEvent,eventScore   scoreEvent  8       olympics.a.score,olympics.a.eventId 4       100.00      Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

My next query has takes 0.106 secs to run...

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    50000   100.00      Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED     results     ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    49520   100.00      Using filesort
```

In the documentation it says that `ALL` requires a full table scan and this is very bad. It also says that `filesort` requires an extra pass to sort the records, it also says that `Not exists` means MySQL was able to do a `LEFT JOIN` optimization. It is also clear that the first method is using indexes whereas the second method doesn't.

I'm trying to work out what is going on here and what maths is involved. I am running `RESET QUERY CACHE` between tests to ensure one isn't given any sort of unfair advantage. 49520 x 413 x 4 is a lot smaller than 50000 x 49520.

Is it to do with the `id` in the explain plan?

When I'm testing these and other queries it seems that my observations are that the query complexity can be approximated by multiplying items with the same id and adding the result of each id together... Is this a valid assumption?

---

### Additional

As requested in the comments the schema and the queries just in case it helps, but I am not looking for better queries... Merely an explanation of the `EXPLAIN`. The table in question...

```
CREATE TABLE results (
  resultId INT NOT NULL auto_increment KEY, 
  athleteId INT NOT NULL,
  eventId INT NOT NULL,
  score INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (athleteId) REFERENCES athletes(athleteId),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (eventId) REFERENCES events(eventId),
  INDEX eventScore (eventId, score),
  INDEX scoreEvent (score, eventId)
) ENGINE=innodb;
```

The first query...

```
SELECT a.resultId, a.eventId, a.athleteId, a.score
FROM results a 

-- Find records with matching eventIds and greater scores
LEFT JOIN results b 
ON b.eventId = a.eventId 
AND b.score > a.score

-- Find records with matching scores and lesser testIds
LEFT JOIN results c
ON c.eventId = a.eventId
AND c.score = a.score
AND c.resultId < a.resultId

-- Filter out all records where there were joins
WHERE c.resultId IS NULL 
AND b.resultId IS NULL;
```

The second query...

```
SELECT resultId, athleteId, eventId, score
FROM (
  SELECT resultId, athleteId, eventId, score
  FROM results
  ORDER BY eventId, score DESC, resultId
) AS a
GROUP BY eventId;
```

I also noticed that if I drop the index `eventScore` that the query drops down to 2.531 secs and the execution plan doesn't so much change but the order of the possible_keys changes and it's not `Using index` for table `b` (ignore the slight changes in row counts I am generating data each time I change the schema)...

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys               key         key_len ref                                 rows    filtered    Extra
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   SIMPLE      a       ALL     NULL                        NULL        NULL    NULL                                47457   100.00  
1   SIMPLE      b       ref     eventId,scoreEvent          eventId     4       olympics.a.eventId                  659     100.00      Using where; Not exists
1   SIMPLE      c       ref     PRIMARY,eventId,scoreEvent  scoreEvent  8       olympics.a.score,olympics.a.eventId 5       100.00      Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

Comment: You might want to post the actual queries and the schema.  It's kinda hard to figure this out just from the explain output.

Comment: Excellent question! It seems that two queries are different: first query filtered data using few conditions, but 2nd query didn't apply any filter condition.

Comment: Yes, my guess is right without viewing your queries. First query has multiple WHERE conditions, so it need more execution time.

Comment: Instead of running `RESET QUERY CACHE` after every query, you can just add `SQL_NO_CACHE` to the query.  i.e. `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM table`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact when you see  you should not to multiply, but sum this numbers.
In you case compare (49520 x 413 x 4) and (50000 + 49520).

Gereral rule is simple: summarize all segments (DERIVED, PRIMARY) and multiply rows within each segment.

```
id select_type  ... rows
1  PRIMARY           1
1  PRIMARY           2
2  DERIVED           3
2  DERIVED           4
3  DERIVED           5
3  DERIVED           6
```

Complexity is: 1*2 + 3*4 + 5*6

Answer (score 0):

Don't put too much trust in the "rows" Statement of EXPLAIN. As in the mysql docs: "*Estimate* of rows to be examined" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html).

Perhaps updating your index statistics will give you a better estimate (OPTIMIZE TABLE, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html)